# Post Correspondence Problem is undecidable

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines, np-complete, undecidability

I am reading Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser and I am in chapter 5. It says here that the Post Correspondence Problem is undecidable, but thinking about it, given a collection, if someone permutes using the algorithm:

```
try every single permutation of the collection:
    if it is a match return True
If nothing was found after trying all permutation return False
```

This should decide if there is a match in $O(n!)$ as I understand the problem, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are missing the fact that the indices that you need to select do not need to be a permutation. In fact you can use the same index multiple times (or never).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can use the same domino multiple times, thanks myself.